# Why is can't the wave function travel in the opposite direction in this problem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, particle-physics

So the problem is a step-potential problem as shown in the following problem

[image: pic]

The general solution is as follows

[image: pic]

What I don't understand about this general solution is the fact the B<- is given as 0 in the picture, whilst the general solution allows for B<- to be anything. So why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflections of particles can occur due to changes in potentials. There is no change in potential for $x>0$ in this problem, and there is no source of particles within $x>0$. That means there can be no particles traveling in the $-x$ direction in that region.

If there was another potential energy step, or even a gradual slope to the potential, in the $x>0$ region we would need to include a non-zero $e^{-k_2 x}$ term.

Comment: I have understood your answer, however it hinges on me accepting that a matter wave can not reflect if there is no change in potential. Therefore could I ask for maybe an explaination of why changes in potential result in reflections, I am beginning QM which is why I have these misunderstandings, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Hello123  If we have a defined potential which changes, then there must be a force. The magnitude of the force at a point is $\frac{dV}{dx}$ at that point. If the the potential is constant in some region, there is no force on the particle therefore no change in velocity$\to$ no reflection.